# How do I get the text to align to the top in UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Running Xcode 8.3.3 I have a UITextView that fills the entire view. However, the text does not align to the top but has more than 80 points padding at the top - see attached screenshot.

I have worked with constraints, alignment and searched documentation but cannot see how to resolve this issue.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: using storyboard text is by default aligned to top of the textView

Comment: Followup question then. If it is aligned to the top by default, why is my text not doing the default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to auto-layout. If you look at the positioning of the textView screenshot in the question you can see that the textView is positioned relative to the navigation bar and not the View. By moving the top position up (see screenshot below) the text alignment issue is resolved.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay based on your query I had tried one solution please have a look at this

1) Here is first output with space which you are getting by default

I used following code to show actually what is happening there, I am using a textView that covers my full screen from top to bottom From storyboard

```
 //Outlet
 @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

 //call the function and assign to TextView
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        adjustContentSize(tv: myTextView)
    }

    //this will Add the respected boundaries to textView content 
    func adjustContentSize(tv: UITextView){
        let deadSpace = tv.bounds.size.height - tv.contentSize.height
        let inset = max(0, deadSpace/2.0)

        tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(inset, tv.contentInset.left, inset, tv.contentInset.right)
    }

    //Will check when value is changed
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        self.adjustContentSize(tv: textView)
    }
```

--Simulator Output

[image]

2) As expected output

--Code

```
//Outlet
 @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

 //call the function and assign to TextView
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        adjustContentSize(tv: myTextView)
    }

//this will Add the respected boundaries to textView content 
    func adjustContentSize(tv: UITextView){
        tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, tv.contentInset.left, 0,tv.contentInset.right)
    }

    //Will check when value is changed
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        self.adjustContentSize(tv: textView)
    }
```

--Expected Output

[image]

Hope it Helps you :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to work this through. as I tried it I still had the same problem. Please see my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Use textContainerInset to align the text with the textView top 
`textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

You can get use the left, bottom and right inset from the existing textContainerInset if you want just the top inset to change.